# Output custom post meta onto a specific template page

Tags: wordpress, post

I don't understand why its so hard to find an answer to this... But I really hope to because it is one of the things holding me back from releasing my theme..

To output or put the metabox option to use you would use code like this

```
 <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'MoonRock_page_background_image', true); ?>
```

This is using wordpresses get_post_meta.

I am having a problem because I am trying to have a user upload a logo inside a custom post type and have that option outputted not on that page/post, but onto a template file, specifically the home template file I made.

There is a banner with an unordered list of 6 logo spots, I am trying to display the images the user uploads inside the clients post type.

Here is the UL code with some various PHP

```
    <!-- Press Banner -->

<div id="press-banner">
  <div class="span11 center nofloat clearfix">
    <h2>some of our clients</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="press-banner-logo-fastco" src="#" href="#" target="_blank"><img src=" <?php echo $text; ?>"/></a></li>
      <li><a class="press-banner-logo-time" href="#" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_moon_logo_image', true); ?>"/></a></li>
      <li><a class="press-banner-logo-forbes" href="#" target="_blank"><img src="<?php moon_opts_show('press-banner-three',TEMPLATE_URI .'/images/logo.png'); ?>"/></a></li>
      <li><a class="press-banner-logo-techcrunch" href="#" target="_blank"><img src="<?php moon_opts_show('press-banner-four',TEMPLATE_URI .'/images/logo.png'); ?>"/></a></li>
      <li><a class="press-banner-logo-pandodaily" href="#" target="_blank"><img src="<?php moon_opts_show('press-banner-five',TEMPLATE_URI .'/images/logo.png'); ?>"/></a></li>
      <li><a class="press-banner-logo-betabeat" href="#" target="_blank"><img src="<?php moon_opts_show('press-banner-six',TEMPLATE_URI .'/images/logo.png'); ?>"/></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div> 
<!-- End Press Banner -->
```

This code actually works, but it works with the nhp options framework I am using... Only significant differance I noticed was instead of get_post_meta were using a custom function..

Here is the code for that function...

```
    /**
 * This is used to echo and option value from the options array
 */
function moon_opts_show($opt_name, $default = null){
    global $moon_Options;
    $option = $moon_Options->get( $opt_name, $default );
    if( ! is_array( $option ) ){
        echo $option;
    }   
}
```

I dont understand it, I kind of do, but I still wouldnt know how to use that inside my metabox code, I wouldnt know what variables to get and stuff..

So I am a little lost between if that is the solution to output the image into my homepage template, or if maybe I need to use WP_Query I have a few options in mind but its giving me a hard time.. So I ask for a little help.. please oh please im begging hehe...

EDIT: I am going to add the original question into simple terms...

Image post meta WILL out put onto the specific post, I have a clients post type, and a file called single-clients.php, when I create a new post all the meta data changes the content on that specific page... Obviously if I have a client post named WILL SMITH the featured image will apply to only WILL SMITH, and that goes for meta info, such as text and images.

What I would like to learn/acheive is outputting the image meta from WILL SMITH onto the homepage, I already see that I would need unique IDS and such, boy I am confused..

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution and as I guessed it was an easy one.

By putting it inside a WP_Query or a loop I guess you would call it, the meta data outputted onto my homepage template

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'clients', 'posts_per_page' => 6 ) );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
           the_post_thumbnail(); 

           echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_moon_logo_image', true); 

        endwhile;
```

?>

Inside the endwhile I can add anything I want from my clients posts, or portfolio posts.. etc I am sure 99% of themers and any wordpress expert knows that, but I am working my way up to the expert level.. gotta learn sometime..